# Impute different types of variables with MICE

Tags: r, missing-data, imputation, r-mice

I am trying to perform imputation on a dataset which has 69 columns and over 50000 rows. My dataset has different types of variables:

1. columns that only present binary variables (0,1)
2. categorical columns
3. columns that take continuous numerical data

Now, I want to perform imputation and I know that my columns have a high level of multicollinearity.

Do I have to split my dataset into 3 different subsets (one for each of 1), 2), 3) type of column that I can have) or should I perform imputation on the whole dataset?

The problem is that the package mice have different methods for each of these types. And if I run three different times, do I have to take into consideration the whole dataset or only that specific part?

Comment: the idea behind m.i.c.e is to use all the variables / data - mice does a good job of selecting the appropriate model for each outcome, but you should check. I also believe that mice (or some package built using mice) may offer penalized methods (which may reduce any unwanted effect of collinearity)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can input your whole dataset at once to mice.
(you can actually specify which method to use for each variable separately)

I am citing from the mice reference:

**Parameter 'method'**

> Can be either a single string, or a vector of strings with length length(blocks), specifying the imputation method to be used for each column in data. If specified as a single string, the same method will be used for all blocks. The default imputation method (when no argument is specified) depends on the measurement level of the target column, as regulated by the defaultMethod argument. Columns that need not be imputed have the empty method "". See details.